# No atomics in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-2017

According to the [chrome feature status](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4570991992766464) page chrome should have this enabled by default starting version 60 but `SharedArrayBuffer` and `Atomics` are `undefined` on the following:

- Desktop Chrome 65 Linux
- Desktop Chrome 67 Canary MacOSX High Sierra
- Desktop Chrome 65 Windows 10

Instead on all of these there is a flag in `chrome://flags` to enable them. Note that node.js 8.x *does* have them enabled by default. Why do I not have these available?

Comment: I interpret "enabled by default" in that link to mean the code is compiled into Chrome by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow that status link and go to its documentation line you end up on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer

Under compatibility you'll note Chrome gets as asterisk with the note:

> Chrome disabled SharedArrayBuffer on January 5, 2018 to help reduce the efficacy of speculative side-channel attacks. This is intended as a temporary measure until other mitigations are in place.